# React UseEffect and Unsubscribe promise with conditional listener ! (Optimize Firestore onsnapshot)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-effect

I never find a solution for my useEffect probleme : 
I'm useing firebase and create a listener (onSnapshot) on my database to get the last state of my object "Player" I can get when the states `currentGroup` and `currentUser` are available

```
const [currentGroup, setCurrentGroup] = useState(null)
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null)
const [currentPlayer, setCurrentPlayer] = useState(null)

const IDefineMyListener = () =>{

    return firebase.doc(`group/${currentGroup.id}${users/${currentUser.id}/`)
       .onSnpashot(snap =>{
            //I get my snap because it changed
            setCurrentPlayer(snap.data())
       }) 
}
```

Juste above, i call a useEffect when the `currentGroup` and `currentUser` are available and (IMPORTANT) if I didn't already set the `currentPlayer`

```
 useEffect(() => {

   if (!currentGroup || !currentUser)  return

   if (!currentPlayer) {
     let unsubscribe = IDefineMyListener()
     return (() => {
        unsubscribe() 
     })
   }

},[currentGroup,currentUser])
```

As you can think,  `unsubscribe()` is called even if the `IDefineMyListener()` is not redefined. In other words, when `currentGroup` or `currentUser` changes, this `useEffect` deleted my listener whereas I NEED IT.

How can i figure out ?!

PS :if I remove `if (!currentPlayer)`, of course it works but will unlessly get my data

PS2 : If I remove the unsubscribe, my listener is called twice each time.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `useCallback` hook to work around this.

First we'll define your listener using `useCallback` and give the dependency array the arguments as `currentGroup` and `currentUser`.

```
const IDefineMyListener = useCallback(event => {

   return firebase.doc(`group/${currentGroup.id}${users/${currentUser.id}/`)
   .onSnpashot(snap =>{
        //I get my snap because it changed
        setCurrentPlayer(snap.data())
   })

}, [currentGroup, currentUser]);
```

And we will only use `useEffect` to register and deregister your listener.

```
useEffect(() => {   

   //subscribe  the listener
   IDefineMyListener()

     return (() => {
        //unsubscribe the listener here
        unsubscribe() 
     })
   }

},[])
```

Since we passed an `[]` to useEffect, it will only run once when the component is mounted. But we have already registered the callback. So your callback will run everytime the `currentGroup` or `currentUser` changes without deregistering your listener.

Comment: You forget `let unsubscribe =   IDefineMyListener()`, right ?
By the way, the useCallback is only called once and never when `currentGroup`or `currentUser` change after the first call... 

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question, I had duplicated a line

Comment: I am a little bit confused.
You will subscribe the listener in the `useEffect`, and then the listener will give you latest value by `.snapshot`.
Your listener's  data would be changed (because group and user data is changed).
`useCallback` is only getting called once because `currentGroup` and `currentUser` might be nested objects. 

You might want to provide the appropriate key which can unqiuely identify the change.
Or you might want to deep compare both the objects (prev, curr) and then accordingly pass a flag to `useCallBack`.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I think my probleme was, I didn't understood the unsubscribe() concept.  I wrote down an answer. it works like a charm, thank you for your patience :)

Comment: It might still be worthwhile to use what I gave as an implementation with `useCallBack`.
Because `useEffect` will run on every change (according to its dependencies) and you will have to place lot of `if` blocks to prevent unwanted changes. 
That is why for these scenarios,  `callBack` pattern is preferable. 
You can read it here : https://codedaily.io/tutorials/72/Creating-a-Reusable-Window-Event-Listener-with-useEffect-and-useCallback. Please upvote/accept my answer if it was of any help to you. :)

Comment: Yes, i will read this tutorial, because I couldn't figured out how to use "useCallback"  to do what I needed. I let you know. Thank you @Utsav

Answer (score 1):

The problem was about my bad understanding of the unsubscribe() .
I didn't return anything in my useEffect, but save my unsusbcribe function to call it when i need.

```
let unsubscribe = null //I will save the unsubscription listener inside it
const myComponent = () => {

  const [currentGroup, setCurrentGroup] = useState(null)
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null)
  const [currentPlayer, setCurrentPlayer] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentGroup || !currentUser)  {
      if(unsubscribe){
        unsubscribe() // 2 - when I dont need of my listener, I call the unsubscription function
      }
      return
    }

    if (!currentPlayer && !unsubscribe) {
      unsubscribe = IDefineMyListener()  // 1 -  I create my listener and save the unsubscription in a persistant variable
    }
  },[currentGroup,currentUser])

  const IDefineMyListener = () =>{
      return firebase.doc(`group/${currentGroup.id}${users/${currentUser.id}/`)
        .onSnpashot(snap =>{
              //I get my snap because it changed
              setCurrentPlayer(snap.data())
        }) 
  }

  ...
```